# While updating the entity in MS CRM 2015 error message

Tags: c#, crm

I have an incident form in crm 2015.  After spme operations the incident entity becomes passive. In my database the passive incident is to be understood by  looking the state and status columns. If the incident is passive the statecode becomes 1 and the status code becomes 5.

After the incident becomes to be passive. I want to do someyhing to that incident entity.

As an operator I want to change the state and status to activate the incident. (state=0,status=1)

If I success I want to update the new_anketgonderildi field (bit field) to true. Then make the incident again passive and update the entity.

But I got an error while updating the entity.

> This case has already been resolved. Close and reopen the case record to see the updates.

I realized that if the incident is active I can change the new_anketgonderildi field. When the incident is in passive situation I can not change. To change the bit value field I have to activate the incident change the bit field and then deactivate the incident again.

How can I achieve this situation ? [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkeT.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkeT.jpg)

Comment: Please edit to use Markdown formatting, especially for the image block.

Comment: have you visited this [link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/143473)?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way CRM works. There are a number of entities (including case/incident) which once made inactive (passive) can no longer be edited.

You will need to either;

1. Update `new_anketgonderildi` before you close the case.
2. Reactivate the closed case, update `new_anketgonderildi`, and then close the case again.

There is an example of the later within [Sample: Validate record state and set the state of the record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh547422.aspx).

```
private void SetState(EntityReference caseReference)
{
    // Open the incident

    // Create the Request Object
    SetStateRequest state = new SetStateRequest();

    // Set the Request Object's Properties
    state.State = new OptionSetValue((int)IncidentState.Active);
    state.Status = new OptionSetValue((int)incident_statuscode.WaitingforDetails);

    // Point the Request to the case whose state is being changed
    state.EntityMoniker = caseReference;

    // Execute the Request
    SetStateResponse stateSet = (SetStateResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(state);  
}


private void CloseIncident(EntityReference caseReference)
{
    // Close the Incident

    // Create resolution for the closing incident
    IncidentResolution resolution = new IncidentResolution
    {
        Subject = "Case Closed",
    };

    resolution.IncidentId = caseReference;

    // Create the request to close the incident, and set its resolution to the 
    // resolution created above
    CloseIncidentRequest closeRequest = new CloseIncidentRequest();
    closeRequest.IncidentResolution = resolution;

    // Set the requested new status for the closed Incident
    closeRequest.Status = new OptionSetValue((int)incident_statuscode.ProblemSolved);

    // Execute the close request
    CloseIncidentResponse closeResponse = (CloseIncidentResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(closeRequest);
}
```